# manipulate JSON array in Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to store an JSON Array in MySQL with Spring and Hibernate.

The application gets the likes from the users and stores the id of a user in a JSON Array, for example

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

in a column name `likes`with type `text` (MySQL)

¿How can I put a new id in the array? I mean, get the JSON form database and insert the id and count the number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `transient` variables as a solution for this problem. I don't think there is a better solution for this. You may also try hibernate `interceptors` for this as a solution.

```
@Table
@Entity(name='Likes')
public class LikesEntity implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    private List<String> userIds;
    @Column
    private String likes;
    @Column
    private String count;

     //getter and setters for the like and count
    ...
    public void addUserId(String id){
        this.userIds.add(userIds);
        this.likes = convertToJsonArray(userIds); // use GSON or Jackson or any other library that can help you convert array to JSON string
        this.count = this.userIds.size();
    } 


}
```

within your service layer do the following

```
 @Transactional(lockmode = LockMode.READ){
   LikesEntity le = sess.get(LikesEntity.class,234);
   le.addUserId("userPk");
   session.saveOrUpdate(le);
 }
```